# Решить матричное уравнение C++

Tags: c++, матрицы

Есть матрица `A[NxN]`
Есть матрица `B[MxM]`

Необходимо решить уравнение:
`|A*(w^2)+B| == 0`
относительно вектора `w`

Как это осуществить на c++?
Спасибо!

Comment: А как решить матричное уравнение вы знаете?

Comment: А N и M какие ?